# Как в Python прописать условие if, чтобы получить ожидаемый ответ?

Tags: python, if, распознавание-речи, speechbrain

Прохожу циклом по папкам с файлами, где записаны голоса разных людей: в каждой папке `spk` директории `speakers` - голоса одного человека в отдельных файлах.

Есть две переменных-счетчика: общее количество проходов `num_total` и количество положительных ответов `num_true` (при сравнении дали тензор tensor([True])).

Если я не в порядке цикла, а вручную подставляю в метод библиотеки speechbrain для сравнения 2 голоса одного человека, система их сравнивает корректно и дает положительный тензор true. Однако распечатав переменные-счетчики из цикла, вижу: `num_true` равен нулю. Что не так?

Код:

```
# подход распознавания на основе ECAPA: сравниваем голоса 
!pip install speechbrain
from speechbrain.pretrained import SpeakerRecognition
import os
from itertools import combinations


num_true=0
num_total=0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers'):
    if not files:
        continue
    res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей: [(файл 1, файл 2), (файл 1, файл 3)...(файл 3, файл 4)]
    # print(res)

    for tuples in res:         # идем по каждому кортежу в списке
        verification = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
        score, prediction = verification.verify_files(os.path.join(root, tuples[0]), os.path.join(root, tuples[1]))
        num_total+=1
        if prediction == 'tensor([True])':
            num_true+=1

# считаем метрику accuracy:
# if num_total !=0:
#   accuracy = num_true/num_total
#   print(accuracy)
# else:
#   print('На ноль делить нельзя')

# распечатываем переменные-счетчики:
print(num_true)
print(num_total)
print(prediction, type(prediction) ) # для примера выполнил отдельно для одного сравнения файлов
# 0
# 44
# tensor([True]) <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

Comment: ну напечатай prediction да посмотри, что там. Уж наверняка не строка "tensor([True])"

Comment: @Эникейщик, в том и загвоздка, что она самая

Comment: добавьте в вопрос вывод print(prediction, type(prediction)

Comment: @Эникейщик, добавил - выше виден сам ответ и класс объекта торча. В данном случае это вывод для одного из вариантов сравнений

Comment: ну и где же строка-то??? написано же class torch.Tensor :)

Comment: попробуйте так ``torch.eq(verification, tensor([True]))``. Перед этим import torch

Comment: @Эникейщик, ругается: name 'tensor' is not defined. Сделал так: `torch.eq(verification, torch.tensor([True]))`, и словил иную ошибку: мол, ожидалась комбинация `(Tensor input, Tensor other, *, Tensor out)` или комбинация `(Tensor input, Number other, *, Tensor out)`, я же, вроде как передал `(SpeakerRecognition, Tensor)`

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае сам объект `prediction` это метод, его значение не есть строкой с которой вы его сравниваете. Если хотите сравнивать его со своей строкой вам нужно написать так:

```
if str(prediction) == 'Tensor([True])':
```

Или так:

```
if prediction.__str__() == 'Tensor([True])':
```

Таким образом вы просите свой объект `prediction` вернуть его строковое значение и тогда уже сравниваете две строки.

Comment: О. так даже еще проще

Comment: Дайте знать если сработало

Comment: @Max, сделал еще одним способом - ответ привел ниже

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу еще одним способом: благодаря общему разуму, реализовал так:

```
if prediction == torch.tensor([True]):
    ...
```

Все прочее, как указал в коде ранее